# OutOfRangeExeption в перегрузке оператора

Tags: c#, строки, библиотеки, перегрузка-операторов

Здравтсвуйте, не получается отловить исключение. Когда использую оператор неявного приведения в строку - выбрасывает исключение. Вот код, помогите чем сможете:

```
public class BoolMatrix
{
    private bool[,] matrix;

    public bool this[int a, int b]
    {
        get
        {
            return matrix[a, b];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                Count++;
            matrix[a, b] = value;
        }
    }

    public BoolMatrix(int width, int heigth)
    {
        matrix = new bool[width, heigth];
        Length = width*heigth;
        Heigth = heigth;
        Width = width;
        Count = 0;
    }

    static public implicit operator string(BoolMatrix a)
    {
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Heigth; j++)
            {
                s += a[i, j] + " ";
            }
            s += '\n';
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Это был библиотечный класс, а теперь сам вызов оператора:

```
string s = new BoolMatrix(9, 6);
```

Кстати, если задать одинаковое кол-во строк и столбцов - работает как часы.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и посмотрите конкретные значения переменных в момент возникновения исключения. Постарайтесь локализовать ошибку. Приведите в вопросе минимальный пример для её воспроизведения.

Comment: Я к тому,  что может у вас там mtx пустой,  а кода работы с ним в вопросе нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут у вас ширина - высота.

```
matrix = new bool[width, heigth];
```

А в цикле прогоняете сначала по `Height`, а нужно, как понимаю, по `Width` вот так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.Heigth; j++)
        {
            s += a[i, j] + " ";
        }
        s += '\n';
    }
```